# Consulta sobre tabla y Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

¿Cómo estan? Necesitaría la iluminación de ustedes, tengo un programa que debe registrar la venta de **n** productos. La venta puede tener muchos productos, pero para ello debo tener un **único identificador de venta.** En este caso, como la venta del producto refiere a verduras, se nos sugirió usar el remito como dato único de venta. El problema es que, de la forma en que lo haga no puedo duplicar ese remito ya que debe ser único. Lo hice como campo `PRYMARY KEY` y como `UNIQUE` pero esto me da el siguiente error a la hora de hacer el `INSERT`:

```
'Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Ventas__B9CD6610622A7841'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Ventas'. The duplicate key value is (1234-56789123).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La composición de mis tablas es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes(
idCliente INT IDENTITY(1,1),
dni BIGINT,
nombre VARCHAR(30),
apellido VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(100),
telefono BIGINT,
idBorrado BIT,
CONSTRAINT pkIdCliente PRIMARY KEY(idCliente)
)

INSERT INTO Clientes
VALUES(36146955,'Mario','Pepito','mail@mail.com',123456, 0)

CREATE TABLE Vacios(
idVacio INT IDENTITY(1,1),
descripcion INT,
CONSTRAINT pkIdVacio PRIMARY KEY(idVacio)
)

INSERT INTO vacios
VALUES(1), (2)

CREATE TABLE Productos(
codProducto VARCHAR(30),
descripcion VARCHAR(50),
idBorrado BIT,
CONSTRAINT pkCodProducto PRIMARY KEY (codProducto)
)

INSERT INTO Productos
VALUES('001-2','Acelga penca verde', 0), ('002-1','Achicoria', 0), ('016-2','Berenjena negra', 0)

CREATE TABLE Ventas(
nroRemito VARCHAR(13) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
precioUnitario MONEY NOT NULL,
subTotal MONEY NOT NULL,
total MONEY NOT NULL,
fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
nroFactura VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
codProducto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
idCliente INT,
idVacio INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_cliente FOREIGN KEY (idCliente) REFERENCES clientes(idCliente),
CONSTRAINT fk_vacio FOREIGN KEY (idVacio) REFERENCES vacios(idVacio)
)

INSERT INTO Ventas
VALUES(1234567891234, 12,5,6,4, GETDATE(), 12,028-2, 1,2)

create table DetalleVenta(
idDetalle int identity(1,1),
idVenta varchar(13),
idCajachica int,
subTotal money,
constraint pkIdDetalle primary key (idDetalle)
)
```

Imagen para iluminar el proceso de inserción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se ve en azul es el código único de venta, el remito. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema de inserción?

Comment: Qué significa *remito*? Qué representa?... No olvidemos que una venta tiene una **cabecera** y **n detalles**. La cabecera (dbo.Venta) tiene datos generales sobre la venta, incluyendo su Id, Fecha, IdCliente, etc. El detalle (dbo.VentaDetalle) puede llevar en cada fila el Id de producto vendido, la cantidad de items, el precio unitario, etc; e **INCLUYE el IdVenta**, que hace referencia a la cabecera. No veo el detalle de la venta en tu pregunta

Comment: El remito es un documento que surge de la obligación del vendedor de entregar la mercadería, y deja constancia de ello. He añadido el VentaDetalle, pero se me han mezclado los temas. @Arriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el error pone que estás insertando valores duplicados, por lo que entiendo que en nroRemito, teniendo UNIQUE, puede ocurrir lo siguiente:

- Estás insertando una o más filas que ya están insertadas en la tabla; al ser UNIQUE, te da el error ya que no permite valores duplicados.
- También podría ocurrir si intentas actualizar cualquier valor con un nroRemito que ya existe (lo cual no es en este caso, ya que estás haciendo un insert).

Por tanto entiendo que ocurre lo primero; prueba a hacer una sentencia SELECT a ver si ese dato ya existe:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ventas
WHERE nroRemito = '1234567891234'
```

Y comprueba que no te devuelve ningún valor. Si te devuelve una fila, que seguramente sea eso, estás intentando insertar una fila que ya existe, y al ponerle **UNIQUE**, no te lo permite.

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta, me he equivocado. Actualmente, ese idVenta ya no está en la tabla. El campo nroRemito es UNIQUE y es lo único que está

Comment: De acuerdo! Miro de nuevo la pregunta modificada y te digo

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Creo que aparece ese error porque quizás estás introduciendo un valor que ya existe. Échale un vistazo.